# Alternate colors for nested DIVs without JQuery

Tags: html, css

I'm elaborating a tree structure with nested `DIV`s. Well, rather than "nested" I'd call them "matrioshked", since every `DIV` can contain dynamically generated children, grandchildren and so on, having each one its own `DIV` inside that of the parent.

Is there a way to alternate the background color of the elements? Of course the usual "even" and "odd" used for rows and lists can't work, and *a priori* I don't know how many layers there will be, so I can't declare a div div div div etc. style.

I know I can insert inside every child `DIV` an 1x1 image with an `ONLOAD` checking the color of the parent and using the alternate for the child, but I hope to find a more practical (and elegant) solution.

P.S.
I can't use JQuery for compatibility issues.

edit:

Here is, more or less, what I have to do: http://jsfiddle.net/gmw3t8rd/

Comment: I would like to see the code. Can you please show me fiddle?

Comment: Please leave me the time to write it :-)

Comment: please give fiddle example the html structure

Comment: Use CSS  `:nth-child (odd || even)`.

Comment: @MarcoBernardini You can't use jQuery for compatibility issues, that's a first. The only way to do what you're asking (if I understand it correctly) is with JavaScript, whether you use jQuery shorthand or not.

Comment: @w3debugger - I added a link to a quick fiddle, to show what I need.

Comment: I dont think bro, that this can be done without JavaScript :)

Comment: Are you able to alter the generated HTML (eg. add classes to the `div`s)?

Answer (score 0):

This Problem may be solve is you see this site.
http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listutorial/sub_master.htm

Answer (score 0):

Your description is a bit conflicting with you JSFiddle, but if I now understand what you want, you can just use CSS to apply the desired coloring.

```
#elenco_generi div.g0 {
    background-color: #ffffdd;
}

#elenco_generi div .figli div .figli div, #elenco_generi div .figli div .figli div .figli div .figli div {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#elenco_generi div.g1, #elenco_generi div .figli div, #elenco_generi div .figli div .figli div .figli div, #elenco_generi div .figli div .figli div .figli div .figli div .figli div {
    background-color: #ddddff;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hxgLpw3e/

I know the JSFiddle looks "broken" towards the bottom, but that's because you seemed to stop using `.figli` to wrap your `div`s. It's always a good idea to have a fixed structure on how content will be layered. Trading off just complicates things.

Basically, you use the wrapper `div` ID as your starting point, and just add a level each time. If this isn't want you are looking for, could you try re-explaining it?

Assuming this is what you wanted, I highly recommend you just go with JavaScript, it's a lot cleaner to make happen with expandable content.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this refuse to works as a fiddle, complaining the Javascript function is not defined. In Firefox I went down until there wasn't space enough for the button. Anyway here is everything, reduced at the essential.

The CSS:

```
div {
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
.blue {
    border: 3px solid blue;
    background: #99f;
}
.green {
     border: 3px solid green;
     background: #9f9;
}
```

This is the Javascript snippet:

```
function makeChild(TheDiv) {
    var nextBg = 'blue';
    var thisId = TheDiv.dataset.did;
    var nextId = parseInt(thisId) + 1;
    if (TheDiv.dataset.bg =='blue') {
        var nextBg = 'green';
    }
    var code = '<div class="' + nextBg + '" id="child_' + nextId + '" data-bg="' + nextBg + '" data-did="' + nextId +'">This is a child<br /><br /><input type="button" onclick="makeChild(this.parentNode)" value="OPEN ANOTHER CHILD" /><div id="sonny_' + nextId + '"></div></div>';
    document.getElementById('sonny_' + thisId).innerHTML = code;
}
```

and this is the HTML:

```
<div id="main">

<div class="blue" data-bg="blue" data-did="0">
<input type="button" onclick="makeChild(this.parentNode)" value="OPEN CHILD" />
<div id="sonny_0"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

This makes exactly what I want: nested `DIV`s with alternate colors.

I hope this small trick will be helpful to someone else!

Comment: Works fine in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kbuv3b8c/. You probably had it set to `onLoad` instead of `No wrap - in <head>`. My solution does those alternating colors, but the code you originally provide messes it up (as I noted) due to inconsistent implementation. But, you're welcome for pointing you to JavaScript for a simple solution, though yours could use some tweaking. If you click an earlier button that already has nested `DIV`s, it'll replace them, instead of appending them.

Comment: I've not yet studied all the JSFiddle features. This is a very simple implementation: in the production version the "OPEN CHILD" button will be replaced by a "COLLAPSE", and the child container will host some subcategories. All this stuff is just to make easier for the operators to visualize the various levels: they complained a plain indentation was too difficult to understand :-S